# Ruby gem - How to call a class from a second folder inside lib/?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, directory, require, nameerror

I'm creating a gem called brval, and my folder structure is:

```
lib/
  brval/ ... brval files
  cep/ ...cep files
  brval.rb
```

I can require and use all modules and classes inside `brval/` folder, I just need to add
`require 'brval/file.rb'` inside brval.rb and then use extend or include to add the modules to brval main module.

But for files inside `cep/` folder I can't do that, doesn't work.
I tried to `require 'cep/cep_file'` (is a class) inside `brval.rb` module

But when I build my gem to test it I always got the same error:

`lib/cep/cep_file.rb:1:in '<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Cep(NameError)`

My cep_file module and class structure is:

```rb
module Cep
  class CepFile

  methods...
```

In my gemspec file I also have:

```rb
spec.files         = Dir['lib/**/*', 'README.md']
spec.require_paths = ['lib']
```

Comment: Why does the `cep` folder has to be outside the `brval` folder? Shouldn't the `Cep` module be a submodule of `Brval`? In your case seems like a good pattern would be to have the `bravl.rb` file only deal with `require`s, and have all the modules and classes in the other folders.

Comment: I put cep outside brval folder because cep will only call external API's. But if I change cep folder to `brval/cep/cep_file`, the require will be the same of `brval/files` ?

Comment: The thing is that users of your gem, and your code itself should use `require` in the same manner - `require 'your-gem-name/file'`. This is the reason it is most common to put all of your gem files in the `lib/your-gem-name` folder. If cep is a module of your gem, it should be inside the folder of your gem. I am not sure this is the only problem you are facing now, but it might put you on the right track.

Comment: I believe the problem is something else than file loadin. `module Cep` should not give you `uninitialized constant Cep(NameError)` in any situation, and that is what according to your text, the error comes from. It obviously tries to load the correct file. Are you sure your file doesn't say: `class Cep::CepFile` or something?

Comment: @DannyB is right though that the convention would be that all your files are under `lib/brval`, so `lib/brval/cep/cep_file.rb` + `require 'brval/cep/cep_file`.

Comment: Thank you, put the `cep/` folder inside brval worked here